# Detect active internet connection with "Network" framework in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using "Network" framework to constantly listen to network changes in my application.

Here is the code for reference.

```
import Network

public class NetworkService {
    public static let instance = NetworkService()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "NetworkService")
    private let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    private init() {
        monitorNetwork()
    }
    
    func monitorNetwork() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            
            if path.status != .satisfied {
                print("Disconnected")
            }
            else {
                Print("Connected")
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
}
```

I tested this in real device and it works for the most part. My issue is with one use case.

My issue - I need to know when the iPhone is connected to the wifi with working internet connection.

Here is what I tried (observed).

When the iPhone connects to a wifi (with internet access and without internet access) in both cases callback gives me "path.status" as satisfied.

But "path" object is not same in both cases. I am providing the callback response below.

"path" object, when iPhone connects to Wifi with no internet access.

```
 satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns
  - status : Network.NWPath.Status.satisfied
  ▿ availableInterfaces : 1 element
    ▿ 0 : en0
      - type : Network.NWInterface.InterfaceType.wifi
      - name : "en0"
      - index : 14
      - nw : en0
  - isExpensive : false
  - supportsIPv4 : true
  - supportsIPv6 : false
  - supportsDNS : true
  ▿ internalGateways : 1 element
    ▿ 0 : **.**.**.**
      ▿ hostPort : 2 elements
        ▿ host : **.**.**.** 
          ▿ ipv4 : **.**.**.**
            ▿ address : in_addr
              - s_addr : 19638464
            - interface : nil
        ▿ port : 0
          - port : 0
  - localEndpoint : nil
  - remoteEndpoint : nil
  ▿ nw : Optional<OS_nw_path>
    - some : satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, dns
```

"path" object when iPhone is connected to Wifi with internet access.

```
▿ satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns
  - status : Network.NWPath.Status.satisfied
  ▿ availableInterfaces : 1 element
    ▿ 0 : en0
      - type : Network.NWInterface.InterfaceType.wifi
      - name : "en0"
      - index : 14
      - nw : en0
  - isExpensive : false
  - supportsIPv4 : true
  - supportsIPv6 : true
  - supportsDNS : true
  ▿ internalGateways : 2 elements
    ▿ 0 : **.**.**.** 
      ▿ hostPort : 2 elements
        ▿ host : **.**.**.**
          ▿ ipv4 : **.**.**.**
            ▿ address : in_addr
              - s_addr : 19638464
            - interface : nil
        ▿ port : 0
          - port : 0
    ▿ 1 : **.**.**.** 
      ▿ hostPort : 2 elements
        ▿ host : **.**.**.** 
          ▿ ipv6 : **.**.**.** 
            ▿ address : in6_addr
              - __u6_addr : __C.in6_addr.__Unnamed_union___u6_addr()
            ▿ interface : Optional<NWInterface>
              ▿ some : en0
                - type : Network.NWInterface.InterfaceType.wifi
                - name : "en0"
                - index : 14
                - nw : en0
        ▿ port : 0
          - port : 0
  - localEndpoint : nil
  - remoteEndpoint : nil
  ▿ nw : Optional<OS_nw_path>
    - some : satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, ipv4, ipv6, dns
```

Please notice difference. In second case (with working internet one) ipv6 support is marked true, but it is false when Wifi has no internet access.
[I repeated this observation multiple times it's always the same].

Coming to the question.

Can I base my solution on this observation that if ipv6 support is true, then iPhone is connected to active internet connection?

Or, is there a better way to know that Wifi is connected with working internet access?

Advance apology if question is a duplicate. I tried to find - None is having the clarity I need.

Comment: No, having an IPv6 address simply means that the network has IPv6. You can have a wifi with internet connectivity but no IPv6 and a wifi with no internet connectivity but with IPv6. It just happens that the networks you are testing with have and don't have IPv6. The only way to know if an internet host is reachable is to try and reach it. The Reachability library tries to "ping" a nominated host to determine internet reachability.

Comment: That clears it, when I write the answer I would make sure to put this clarity you provided. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative way you can check the network is not active.

Step 1 is to check if the server response timed out, URLError.Code.timedOut, which suggests a dead connection or your server is not working at the moment.

Step 2 is to verify that it is in fact the internet by trying to connect to a public website, like https://google.com.  If the app fails, it means that the network is wrong, otherwise, the chances that both google server is down and your app's as well is very unlikely.  The probability only gets lower the more websites you try. If it succeeds, then the chance is that the company server is down.